# viewDidLoad, is it called only once?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a beginner in iOS development, and I am following one tutorial using firebase database to make a simple chat app. Actually I am confused with the use of `viewDidLoad` method.

Here is the screenshot of the app: https://ibb.co/gqD4Tw

I don't understand why `retrieveMessage()` method is put on `viewDidLoad` when I want to send data (chat message) to firebase database, I used `sendButtonPressed()` method (which is an `IBAction`) and when I want to retrieve data from the database, I use `retrieveMessage()`.

The `retrieveMessage()` method is called on `viewDidLoad`, as far as I know the `viewDidLoad` method is called only once after the view is loaded into memory. We usually use it for initial setup.

So, if `viewDidLoad` is called only once in initial setup, why the `retrieveMessage()` method can retrieve all the message that I have sent to my own database over and over again, after I send message data to the database ?

I don't understand why `retrieveMessage()` method is put on `viewDidLoad` below is the simplified code:

```
class ChatViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    var messageArray = [Message]()

    @IBOutlet var messageTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var messageTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Set as the delegate and datasource :
        messageTableView.delegate = self
        messageTableView.dataSource = self

        //the delegate of the text field:
        messageTextfield.delegate = self

        retrieveMessage()

        ///////////////////////////////////////////

    //MARK: - Send & Recieve from Firebase

    @IBAction func sendPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    // Send the message to Firebase and save it in our database

    let messageDB = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("message")
    let messageDictionary = ["MessageBody":messageTextfield.text!, "Sender": FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.email]

        messageDB.childByAutoId().setValue(messageDictionary) {
            (error,ref) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            } else {
                self.messageTextfield.isEnabled = true
                self.sendButton.isEnabled = true
                self.messageTextfield.text = ""
            }   
        }
    }

    //Create the retrieveMessages method :

    func retrieveMessage () {
        let messageDB = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("message")

        messageDB.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String:String]

            let text = snapshotValue["MessageBody"]!
            let sender = snapshotValue["Sender"]!

            let message = Message()
            message.messsageBody = text
            message.sender = sender

            self.messageArray.append(message)

            self.messageTableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you added observer in that method thats'y if you add message then it automatically reflected

Comment: In `retrieveMessage` function there is an `observe` closure, from within that closure `messageArray` and `messageTableView` get updated. So in `viewDidLoad` you only start the observation, from then on the observer updates your data and UI continuously.

Answer (score 5):

`viewDidLoad` method is called only once in ViewController lifecycle.

The reason `retrieveMessage()` is called in `viewDidLoad` because it's adding observer to start listening for received and sent message. Once you receive or send message then this block(observer) is called and 
 then adding that text in array `self.messageArray.append(message)` and updating tableview.

Answer (score 1):

viewDidLoad gets called only once but the firebase functions starts a listener, working in background and syncronizeing data. 
Its called in viewDidLoad because it tells -> When this view loads, start listening for messages.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewDidLoad()` is only called upon initializing the ViewController.
If you want to have a function called every time the user looks at the VC again (e.g. after a segue back from another VC) you can just use `ViewDidAppear()`.
It is also called when `ViewDidLoad()` is called.